# Node.js adding to an object within a loop

Tags: node.js, express, bluebird

I can't seem to figure this out. I'm using Node, Express, and Bluebird for promises. What I'm trying to do is add to an object within a loop. When I console log I get an empty object.

Am I going about this all wrong?

```js
Promise.props({
    rewards: db.query("SELECT title, created_by FROM rewards WHERE team_id = '" + team_id + "'")
}).then(function(results) {
  
    var rewards = [],
    title = results.rewards[0].title;
    created_by = results.rewards[0].created_by,

    for (var i = 0; i < results.rewards.length; i++) {
       Promise.props({
           user: db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '" + results.rewards[i].created_by + "'")
       }).then(function(result) {
            rewards.push({
         created_by: created_by,
         title: title,
         username: result.user[0].username
            });
        });
    }
    console.log(rewards);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're trying to console log before the work has been completed. you need to wait for the nested loop of promises to finish, first.

To do that, collect all the promises into an array and use `Promise.all` to know when they are all completed

```
var promiseList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < results.rewards.length; i++) {

  // hold the promise in a variable
  var p = Promise.props({
    user: db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '" + results.rewards[i].created_by + "'")
  }).then(function(result) {
    rewards.push({
    created_by: created_by,
    title: title,
    username: result.user[0].username
  });

  // collect the promise
  promiseList.push(p);
}

// wait for all of them to finish
Promise.all(promiseList).then(function(){
  console.log(rewards);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Derick!

I made your changes and am getting this error:
`Unhandled rejection TypeError: expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null]`

Comment: oops - had several typos in there. i updated the code just to correct the Promise.all call, and a misspelling of "promiseList". hopefully it will work now